# Enter special characters in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, button, character-encoding, vba

How do I enter special characters in Excel VBA? For example if I want "●" (large interpunct) in some strings, they all appear as "?". I tried to substitute all "●" with `&#9679;` in VBA but it didn't work, simply displayed `&#9679;` in the string.

Comment: Try `"This is a strong bullet - " & ChrW(9679)`. Note that not all GUI components can display unicode; the Immediate window will just show `?`.

Answer (score 2):

Reference Website  - [Unicode and VBA’s ChrW() and AscW() functions](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/11/19/unicode-and-vbas-chrw-and-ascw-functions/)

Here the code for bullet et strong bullet. Use hexadecimal in lieu of long.

```
Sub DisplayBullet()
Cells(1, 1).Value = "This is a bullet - " & ChrW(8226)

Cells(2, 1).Value = "This is a strong bullet - " & ChrW(&H25CF)

End Sub
```

[image]

Important: If you try to display in a MsgBox it's not working.